# Azure SQL Database is losing its capacity

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have created an Azure SQL Database and I have noticed that its capacity is decreasing. Once in a while the database capacity decreases.

I don't save anything to the database.

What can cause this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by capacity? How are you observing this?

Comment: In Azure Portal there is a chart that shows how much space is left. Once in a while the space decreases. Is Azure SQL saving some logs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a feature enabled by default in Sql Azure to help you debug performance issues called the Query Store.  It has a configurable cap on its size, but it writes summary information about query plan performance into your database over time.  This could potentially explain your facts.

Also, there are some mechanisms inside the database that do versioning of changes with background cleanup.   If you are just doing updates to the database of existing data you could see size usage change indirectly from explicit user queries that you invoke right then.

Hope that helps you find your root case.